# I want to navigate through the array when I press right button and reverse array when Left button

Tags: ios, swift

This code runs for the next item in the array but when leftButtonWasClciked then it gives error

```
  @IBAction func rightButtonWasClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        
        NTimeLabel.text = NTimeArrayRemasterd[currentIndex] // Set the text to the element at currentIndex in the array
        currentIndex = currentIndex + 1 == NTimeArrayRemasterd.count ? 0 : currentIndex + 1 // Increment currentIndex
        
    }
```

```
@IBAction func leftButtonWasClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    NTimeLabel.text = NTimeArrayRemasterd[currentIndex] // Set the text to the element at currentIndex in the array
    currentIndex = currentIndex - 1 == NTimeArrayRemasterd.count ? 0 : currentIndex - 1 // Decrement currentIndex
}
```

navigate properly when right and left buttons are pressed

Comment: Could you share with us the error that you get ?

Comment: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[M_IOS.HomeScreen lNamazBtn:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe4b5c0d720'

Comment: Make sure that your `IBOutlet` and `IBAction` of your `lNamazBtn` are set correctly.